# Spacing and newlines in bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

What is the reason why the following fails:

```
if [ 'asdf' == 'eff' ] then
    echo You may go to the party.
else
    echo You may not go to the party.
fi
```

But the following is OK:

```
if [ 'asdf' == 'eff' ]
then
    echo You may go to the party.
else
    echo You may not go to the party.
fi
```

Does `then` have to be on its own line or what are the spacing/newline requirements for it?

Comment: This might help: `help if`

Comment: When you get around to using a `for` statement in `bash` checkout `help for` as well. You'll find a similar syntactical pattern.

Comment: `if condition` must be separated from `then` either by a `;` or a newline.

Comment: @David542 : `if` and `then` are syntactically two separated statements. I don't like this language design either, but we have do live with it. In the same vein, `while` and `do` are separate statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that comes after `if` is a command (or pipeline, or series of commands, or...). If you use

```
if [ 'asdf' == 'eff' ] then
```

...the shell will parse that as the beginning of an `if` statement, containing the command `[ 'asdf' == 'eff' ] then` ... that is, the command `[` (yes, that's a command, synonymous with `test`) with the arguments "`asdf`", "`==`", "`eff`", "`]`", and ... "`then`". Since there's no delimiter, the `then` is treated as just another argument to the `[` command, and it'll keep looking for the `then` on subsequent lines!

Consider this example:

```
if echo some words here then
```

Here, since there's no `]` to be a visual indicator of the end of the test command, it's obvious there's a problem. But while `]` looks like a delimiter, it isn't actually syntactically significant to the shell; it's just another argument to the `[` command.

To prevent this, you need a command delimiter of some sort -- a line break or a semicolon (or technically even `&` though that's a bad idea) before the `then`, so the `then` will be parsed as a keyword rather than just an argument to some other command.

BTW, using `==` in a `[ ]` test isn't standard. bash's builtin version of the `[` command allows it, but some others don't. If you're writing specifically for bash, I'd recommend using `[[ ]]` instead (which has cleaner syntax). If you're writing for portability, use `[ = ]` instead.

So, either of these is ok:

```
if [ 'asdf' = 'eff' ]; then
    ...
```

or

```
if [ 'asdf' = 'eff' ]
then
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for this extensive answer. What do you mean by: `BTW, using == in a [ ] test isn't standard. ` ? For example, what would be a downside of using `==` ?

Comment: @David542 If you use `==` in a `[ ]` test expression, it may fail (as in, print an error message and return failure even if the strings actually match) under some shells. For example, if you use a `#!/bin/sh` shebang or run the script with `sh`, and you're on a [recent Debian or Ubuntu release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.5B), it'll run under dash instead of bash and these tests will fail. If you're using a different OS or distro and it makes the same change that Debian and Ubuntu did, the script will suddenly start failing. This is bad and should be avoided.

Comment: Mind you, if you use `[[ ]]` and run your script under something like dash, it'll also fail. You should only use that or `==` if you're writing specifically for bash. But if you're writing specifically for bash, `[[ ]]` has fewer syntactic gotchas than `[ ]`, so it's preferable. Oh, and `=` works fine in `[[ ]]`, so I tend to use it there as well.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that after the condition you either need new line or `;`

if you do:

```
if [ 'asdf' == 'eff' ]; then
```

this will not fail

You can also do all of it in one line:

```
if [ 'asdf' == 'eff' ]; then echo You may go to the party.; else echo You may not go to the party.;fi
```